# PHP script running at Apache and Linux doesn't create file

Tags: php, file, cron

I need some help as my script doesn't create a file. I want to run this script at cronjob. I am using Debian Linux with PHP and Apache.

My script is locate at /var/www/myapplication folder. I want to create / write a file at /var/www/myapplication/testfolder.

The commands I use in the php script is:

```
echo `whoami`;
exec ('whatever >> testfolder/testing.txt');
```

Folder rights:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 27 09:55 testfolder
```

1. When I run the script directly from browser (http://127.0.0.1/myscript.php)

   - it doesn't create the file (testing.txt)
   - echo whoami says: www-data
2. When I run the script from the server with root rights (su):

php -q /var/www/myapplication/myscript.php >>log3.txt

- it creates the file (testing.txt)
- echo whoami says: root
- log3.txt is created at /var/www/myapplication folder

  3. When I run the script from crontab:

     - - - - - /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/myapplication/myscript.php >>log3.txt
- it doesn't create the file (testing.txt)
- echo whoami says: root
- log3.txt is created at /root folder

Why isn't testing.txt created my I run my script from crontab as a cronjob ?

Comment: Why aren't you using the builtin PHP file functions?

Comment: EM-Creations: Because I want redirect 'whatever' command output to create the necessary file (testing.txt).

Comment: Try `shell_exec`. Also, make sure the www-data user has correct write permissions for the directory.

Comment: EM-Creations: Thank you. I tried shell_exec, but the result is same: testing file is not created, only the log3.txt. log3.txt contains: root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be executing operating system commands directly, there are already functions and objects avaliable in PHP for writing and read files. As well, you shouldn't be giving them permission to be writing files to /. Even though you're running it from localhost, if you ever expose the service you're allowing public users to run operating system commands.

You also mention in your comment that you want to redirect the output of 'whatever' to a file, but I still don't see why you couldn't do this with the PHP provided functions.

Regardless, to answer the original question when you run the script via localhost you're accessing it via Apache which means the user `www-data` is running the PHP script. When you access it via your cronjob you're calling PHP from the commandline and another user is accessing the service.

You can see the error that is being returned from attempting to write to the file by logging in with the user running the cronjob and using `echo exec(...)`.